# Autoresize parent container with drag and drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, draggable

I have three containers which are automatically resized when inner div is resized. Now I want to add drag feature to my code and keep the container auto-resize option like it is in my example. How to do this?

I have found several examples but none of those is working with multiple containers.

```
$(function(){
    $('.inner').resizable({
    });

  /* This is not working
      $('.inner').draggable({
    });

    */



});
```

[**Jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hjtBA/481/)

Comment: What you mean is you need inner divs re-sizable and drag-gable? at the same time??

Comment: Yes. resize works now but I need to enable drag option too so that parent div(class="outer") is resized like it works now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bind events in the same `selector`.

```
$('.inner').resizable({}).draggable({});
```

See in your [**edited fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hjtBA/483/).

**EDIT:**

Use the `containment: parent` option on both divs to constraint movement like in  **[this one](http://jsfiddle.net/hjtBA/487/)**.

**EDIT 2:**

[**This**](http://jsfiddle.net/hjtBA/494/) should solve your problem. A callback function to control outer div height is called on resize.

**EDIT 3**:

[**This last fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LakYy/70/) should match all you request. I took your fiddle in comment and edited it.

Comment: Thanks but parent div(class="outer") resize is not working in your  example.

Comment: Look at second fiddle please.

Comment: It is still not working. In your fiddle parent(class=outer) size is always same. In my original example if you resize inner div larger than parent div ,parent is resized also.

Comment: Please see fiddle: jsfiddle.net/LakYy/3/.Fiddle includes drag feature what I'm looking for, but I don't know how to implement it to my code?

Comment: It's close but still container is not resizing when I drag inner div outside of container. Please see my previous comment

Comment: Thanks again but there is only one container. The problem is that I can not get it work with three containers

Comment: Why not? Give them different ids

Comment: I think because of container height is set from whole document height. Thats why it is not working with multiple containers. $container.height($document.height() - offset.top - scrollbarSafety);

Comment: That depends on the logic of your page, I can't tell from your fiddle. It's working properly.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `draggable` function, draggable objects `position` property will set to `absolute`, So you need to write new function for resizing and dragging.

You can detect dragging statement with `mousemove` and `mouseup` event.

`mousemove` event for when object is on dragging, `mouseup` event for after drag work.

resize event is provided by default.

Check this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hjtBA/495/)**

Comment: Thanks, but if I drag it goes outside of container.Please see fiddle: jsfiddle.net/LakYy/3/.Fiddle includes drag feature what I'm looking for, but I don't know how to implement it to my code?